# How to count the total minutes and seconds in Python

Tags: python

I need to count all the minutes from the third items of the lists from a list.
The answer should be 10.00 (because it's in minutes).
I'm stuck at the error `i is not defined`.
This is the code:

```
def main():
    a=[("a","b", 3.10),
       ("c","d", 3.20),
       ("e","f", 3.30)]
    for i[2] in a:
        c=(i[2]//1)*60
        d=(i[2]-(i[2]//1))*100
        e=c+d
        f=f+e
    g=f%60
    h=f//60
    i=g/100
    f=i+h
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply 2 fixes to make it work:

- use `i` in place of `i[2]` on the `for` loop line
- initialize `f` before the loop:

Relevant part of the code with fixes applied:

```
f=0
for i in a:
    c=(i[2]//1)*60
    d=(i[2]-(i[2]//1))*100
    e=c+d
    f=f+e
```

---

For summing up times in your case, you can use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)s:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import math

a=[("a","b", 3.10),
   ("c","d", 3.20),
   ("e","f", 3.30)]

s = timedelta()
for item in a:
    seconds, minutes = math.modf(item[2])
    s += timedelta(minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds*100)

print s.seconds / 60  # prints 10
```

Comment: can python limit the max of the koma with 0.59 ? means that if it's 0.60 it will become 1.00 (like minutes and seconds), or we must use math logic ?

Comment: @user3528188 ok, see the update in the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: The `for` loop could also be done as `for _, _, i in a`.